# Fetch data inside factory in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON response of this type:

```json
{
"uuid": "c6514be0-cced-43b7-b1f4-e66256c1dcaf",
"title": "Harry Potter",
"author": "6637e87b-c2ce-4774-b812-4e8a09312a40",
}
```

This answer is associated with another one through the author key:

```json
{
"author": "6637e87b-c2ce-4774-b812-4e8a09312a40",
"name": "J.K. Rowling",
}
```

So I have a Book class for first response

```dart
class Book {
  final String uuid;
  final String title;
  final Author author;

  Book({
    required this.uuid,
    required this.title,
    required this.author,
  });
}
```

and an Author class for second response

```dart
class Author {
  final String uuid;
  final String name;

  Book({
    required this.uuid,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```

My question is if there is a method to directly fetch the author during the book factory.
I tried with this method but I can't wait for response:

```dart
factory Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Book(
      uuid: json['uuid'],
      title: json['title'],
      author: fetchAuthor(json['author']),
    );
}
```

Where

```dart
Future<Author> fetchAuthor(authorUuid) async {
  http.Response author = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(apiURLAuthors + authorUuid),
  );
  if (author.statusCode == 200) {
    return Author.fromJson(jsonDecode(utf8.decode(author.bodyBytes)));
  } else {
    throw Exception("Failed to load author $authorUuid");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can call 2 model class(book & author) in another class where you wanted to show. Then create a function to call both the data from these 2 modal class and put it in global variable. Now you can able to access the data of both modal class globally. If you want to create list then you set all values in list variable else you can also create different data type values and save data of that particular index

Comment: Could you give me an example? it could be the right way